# How should I call function AuthenticUser and if function return true, page will redirect to specific url

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using windows authentication to detect whether a user is authorized to view the page.

I want to make another condition by calling `if IsAuthenticUser = true`, it will redirect the page to a specific url. So I should pass property of LoginView to code behind code but now I'm not so sure how to do that.

`display.aspx`

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
<AnonymousTemplate>
Welcome! Your access is denied. 
<asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server"  />
</AnonymousTemplate>    
    <LoggedInTemplate>

        <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" FormatString = "Welcome {0}!" runat="server" />
</LoggedInTemplate>    
</asp:LoginView>
```

`DAL.cs`

```
public Boolean AuthenticUser(string UserLogin)
{
    int recCount;
    string strSql = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM AccessTable WHERE UserLoginId=@UserLoginId";
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(strSql);
    recCount = int.Parse(sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    if (recCount == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question here?

Comment: sorry for my unclear question, i want to make another condition by calling if IsAuthenticUser = true, 
it'll redirect page to specific url, but now i'm not sure how to do that. if i write it on display.aspx page, then how should i redirect the URL?

Comment: Check out page.user.isauthenticated